# How can I parse an object of a bounded type T from JSON from an implicit request?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, play-json

I have some simple messages with implicit `Json.reads` and `Json.formats` defined in their companion objects. All of these messages extend `MyBaseMessage`.

In other words, for any `T <: MyBaseMessage`, `T` is (de)serializable.

These messages represent simple CRUD operations to be performed on a cluster, so there's an Play server that will sit between a CLI sending JSON and the Cluster. Because the operations are simple, I should be able to make some very generic `Action`s on the Play side: when I receive JSON at an endpoint, deserialize the message according to the endpoint and forward that message to the cluster.

My ultimate goal is to do something like this:

```
// AddBooMessage extends MyBaseMessage
def addBoo = FooAction[AddBooMessage]  

// AddMooMessage extends MyBaseMessage
def addMoo = FooAction[AddMooMessage]

// etc. ...
```

So when a request is sent to the route corresponding to the `addBoo` message, the request's JSON will be parsed into an `AddBooMessage` message and pushed to the cluster. Repeat ad nauseam.

I have the following written:

```
  private def FooAction[T <: MyBaseMessage] = Action {
    implicit request =>
       parseAndForward[T](request)
  } 

  private def parseAndForward[T <: MyBaseMessage](request: Request[AnyContent]) = {
    val parsedRequest = Json.parse(request.body.toString).as[T]
    Logger.info(s"Got '$parsedRequest' request. Forwarding it to the Cluster.")
    sendToCluster(parsedRequest)
  }
```

But I find the following error:

> No Json deserializer found for type `T`. Try to implement an implicit `Reads` or `Format` for this type.

However, all of these messages are serializable and have both `Reads` and `Format` defined for them.

I tried passing `(implicit fjs: Reads[T])` to `parseAndForward` in hopes to implicitly provide the `Reads` required (though it should already be implicitly provided), but it didn't help.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hmm, could you post more code? Like the one that defines `addX`?

Comment: @AndreiT. `addX` is a generic marker for the class of methods like `addMoo` and `addBoo` in the above question.

Comment: Is `MyBaseMessage` a sealed trait?

Comment: @AndreiT. It's an abstract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JsValue#as[A]` needs an implicit `Reads[A]` in order to deserialize JSON to some type `A`. That is, the error message you're getting is caused because the compiler can't guarantee there is a `Reads[T]` for any type `T <: MyBaseMessage`. Assuming `sendToCluster` is parameterized the same way, this can easily by fixed by simply requiring an implicit `Reads[T]` in each method call. It sounds like you were close, and just needed to take things a step further by requiring the `Reads[T]` from `FooAction`, as well (since that call is where the type is determined).

```
private def FooAction[T <: MyBaseMessage : Reads] = Action { implicit request =>
  parseAndForward[T](request)
} 

private def parseAndForward[T <: MyBaseMessage : Reads](request: Request[AnyContent]) = {
  val parsedRequest = Json.parse(request.body.toString).as[T]
  Logger.info(s"Got '$parsedRequest' request. Forwarding it to the Cluster.")
  sendToCluster(parsedRequest) // Assuming this returns a `Future[Result]`
}
```

If your intention if you use the above code by manually supplying the type parameter, this will work just fine.

---

There are some other improvements I think you can make here. First, if you always expect JSON, you should require the `parse.json` `BodyParser`. This will return a `BadRequest` if what is received isn't even JSON. Second, `as` will throw an exception if the received JSON cannot be deserialized into the expected type, you can use `JsValue#validate` to do this more safely and `fold` the result to handle the success and error cases explicitly. For example:

```
private def FooAction[T <: MyBaseMessage] = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  parseAndForward[T](request)
} 

private def parseAndForward[T <: MyBaseMessage](request: Request[JsValue]) = {
  request.body.validate[T].fold(
    error => {
      Logger.error(s"Error parsing request: $request")
      Future.successful(BadRequest)
    },
    parsed => {
      Logger.info(s"Got '$parsed' request. Forwarding it to the Cluster.")
      sendToCluster(parsed)
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Right on the button -- added the `(implicit fjs: Reads[T])` as a parameter to `FooAction` and it worked. I also used `Action(parser.json)` (as I'm doing synchronous operations), but added your validation optimization. Very clean. Excellent answer overall. Thanks for taking the time to help out a noob to Play. :)